# HIVE - How it works without a meta store?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I installed Hive 1.2.1 and configured to work with Hadoop 2.7.
But I didn't setup meta store for Hive with Derby or MySQL.

And also I don't have a copy of hive-site.xml under $HIVE_HOME/conf.
My question is how still I am able to create database & tables in Hive. Where all these meta data is stored?

Appreciate your insight.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By default Hive uses Derby and starts metastore (based on derby) in embedded mode. The metastore and hiveserver runs in the same process. I believe hive initializes the metastore for you in embedded mode.

http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/cdh/4-x/4-2-0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_18_4.html